# Application running in debugger connects to webservice in but not when running as windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I've created an application in C# which I run as a Windows Service. This works fine.

I've recently modified it so that it connects to a Web Service. When running in Studio, this new code works fine and connects to the Web Service. However when I run the program as a Windows Service (on the same machine) the program times out as it cannot connect to the Web Service (gives the exception - unable to connect to the remote server).

Can anyone think why this might be happening?

The exception seen when run as a service is:

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled
Message="Unable to connect to the remote server"
Source="System"
StackTrace:
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName,          Object[] parameters)
   at DataExtractionService.uk.co.myserver.Service1.SendEmail(String Message, String Subject, String FromAddress, String[] ToAddress, String[] AttachmentNames, Object[] AttachmentData) in C:\Documents and Settings\administrator.MLR\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\DataExtractionService\DataExtractionService\Web References\uk.co.myserver\Reference.cs:line 111
   at DataExtractionService.APDataExtractor.EmailReport(String message, String subject) in C:\Documents and Settings\administrator.MLR\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\DataExtractionService\DataExtractionService\APDataExtractor.cs:line 610
   at DataExtractionService.APDataExtractor.RunDataExtraction() in C:\Documents and Settings\administrator.MLR\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\DataExtractionService\DataExtractionService\APDataExtractor.cs:line 63
   at DataExtractionService.DataExtractionService.HandleClientComm(Object client) in C:\Documents and Settings\administrator.MLR\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\DataExtractionService\DataExtractionService\DataExtractionService.cs:line 96
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(Object obj)
```

The webservice was just added to the project in the normal way under 'Web References'. The webservice works correctly in Studio.

The relevant part of the exe.config is shown below (I've had to change the name of the server, sorry):

```
<applicationSettings>
<DataExtractionService.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="DataExtractionService_uk_co_myserver_Service1"
    serializeAs="String">
    <value>https://myserver.co.uk/premieremailservice/Service1.asmx</value>
  </setting>
</DataExtractionService.Properties.Settings>
 </applicationSettings>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What user account (look at the Log On tab of the service) is the service running as?

Comment: Hi, It's running as a local system account.

Comment: Can you post more details, maybe some of the connection code, and the exception info?

Comment: Please update you question with more information like the exception, config file details, webservice url

Comment: I've updated my question with the exception

Comment: You could install Fiddler on your PC.  It might give more detailed error information.  http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: You say that it works when you're debugging - are the web services hosted in IIS or the web development server (the web services would likely be running on an odd port, e.g. 8827). If thats the case, are you not running the web services before starting the windows service?

Comment: Check if the windows service is pointing to the correct webservice url?

Comment: To add to @MikeGoatly, I would venture to guess you're pointed to the "localhost" version of your webservices, which only run when you run (F5) the project in VS.  Can you post the relevant portion of your `myservice.exe.config` file?

Comment: Hi Mike - unfortunately not, the webservice is hosted on an external IIS web server which should always be running.

Comment: I've now added the relevant portion of my myservice.exe.config

Comment: ARS - this would be what is defined in the exe.config file? Or do I need to do it somewhere else for a Windows Service?

Comment: I think you're going to have to do some good old fashioned troubleshooting to figure this out, it doesn't seem to be anything obvious.  I would start with @mbeckish recommendation, and use something like Fiddler or WireShark to get down and dirty and see what's going on at the protocol level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the web service running? What type of authentication (if any) does it require? If your Windows service is running under a local account (such as System or Network Service) then it may not have the necessary permissions to connect to something remote.

If this is the case then you need to execute the windows service under a domain account and give that account permissions to talk to the web service, or remove authentication altogether.

When you execute your code in Visual Studio you are running in the context of your own credentials, which I assume are enough to reach the web service.

Comment: The only problem with this idea is that typically if it's an authentication error you're going to get an HTTP 403 - Forbidden, rather than a "unable to connect" error.

Comment: Running under System is likely the problem. Network Service should allow outbound network connections.

Comment: @CodingGorilla Would that be true also for a connection over the TCP transport? I see `HttpWebRequest` in the stack trace but I'm not sure if that necessarily implies the transport mechanism.

Comment: Hi Guys - big thanks to all of you for your suggestions. I got it working in the end by switching the service account from 'local system' to a domain administrator account.

Comment: @kprobst No that wouldn't be true of a pure TCP transport connection, but web services typically don't use pure TCP (hence the name "web services") and based on the stack trace and the inclusion of the `HttpWebRequest` class I think it's safe to say this is indeed an HTTP connection.